# Alterar GridView

Tags: c#, sql

Ola pessoal estou tendo um problema em alterar algumas informações, no caso eu preciso alterar duas colunas de um gridview, mas elas estão vindo diretamente de um banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso alterar esses dois campos(ID_categoria e Desc_categoria)

Form:

```html
private void Mostrar()
{
this.datalista.DataSource = NCategoria.Mostrar();
}
```

Camada de negocio

```html
//Método Mostrar
public static DataTable Mostrar()
{
return new DCategoria().Mostrar();

}
```

Dados:

```html
//metodo mostrar

public DataTable Mostrar()
{
DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("categoria");
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
try
{
 SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexao.Cn;
 SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
 SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
 SqlCmd.CommandText = "spmostrar";
 SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 SqlDataAdapter sqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
 sqlDat.Fill(DtResultado);
}
catch
{
 DtResultado = null;
}
return DtResultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pelo visto parece ser winforms, e você quer alterar o título da coluna.

Você pode fazer de três formas, ou altera na storedProcedure, colocando alias:

```
ID_Categoria as "Categoria",
```

ou altera do `DataGridView` dinamicamente:

```
this.datalista.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Categoria";
```

ou coloca manualmente as colunas no `DataGridView`, desabilita o `AutoGenerateRows` do controle e associa sua coluna do `DataTable` pela propriedade `DataPropertyName`.
Esta última, você pode fazer pela interface gráfica do visual studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]